# Div's overlapping

Tags: css, layout, html

I have a list of div pairs: MainDiv's and infPanel Divs. I need to put infPanel div's upon MainDiv and eliminate distance between MainDiv's.
The best decision that I see is to set image in MainDiv with `background` option and just put infPanel inside MainDiv, but because of some technical requirements it is better to post image through just  tag.

Another solution is to use  `position: absolute;` and with JS set the position for each infPanel, but it will be great to eliminate JS.

Can you suggest more "agile" solution? Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `margin` with negative values.

For example,

```
element{margin-top:-100px;}
```

will "move" the element 100 pixels to the top, overlapping other element.

Note that `margin-top` with negative values works also well with `position:absolute;` if you need to specify a `z-index` to reorder elements. It means that instead of specifying the `top` and `left` for each element, you will "move" the element to the top, according to its actual position (whereas `top` and `left` fix the position according to the page).

Comment: The problem that the infPanel is appear under Main div and z-index doesn't help ((

Comment: @andrii: is it possible to reorder elements in HTML? It will be enough to put the elements in correct z-order. If you cannot do that, than see the edit to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the InfPanel at the bottom of MainDiv, you don't need JS at all, you can do it with CSS:

```
.MainPanel {
  position: relative;
}

.InfPanel {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: The problem that there is a lot of such div groups (.

Comment: Is the height of these divs fixed?